# Windows 10 Text drag and drop

Tags: windows-10, drag-and-drop

Windows 10 has this feature called 'Drag and drop text' which for most/some users might be helpful by for me as a programmer is a pain when coding is there a way to disable it?

Comment: I am not familiar with this feature, or any feature, that would match the description you have provided.  Can you provide a better description, screenshot, anything to help us better understand what you are referring to exactly?

Comment: It basically allows to drag selected text into other text fields or within the same field et cetera without having to press anything basically just dragging it with your mouse

Comment: That is just ordinary Drag and Drop that has been around for many years. It works (normally) in a GUI interface to fields with in a document and, yes, I have seen that. No way I know to disable - it has been part of Windows for a long (long) time.

Comment: Yeah the problem I have it is that it works outside GUI interface to fields with in a document.

Comment: I have used Windows for 2 decades and I never used that feature once.  If there isn't an option within Settings then it likely cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It is application specific. That means you need to search that app setting.

For example in SQL Server Management Studio it is a setting:
`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Drag and drop text editing`
[image: disable text drag and drop]

[In Word and Powerpoint it is similar](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-text-drag-and-drop-in-word-powerpoint):
`Options -> Advanced -> Allow text to be dragged and dropped`